# Printing the JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json, facebook-graph-api

I am learning how to use JavaScript so I wrote a simple script that prints out all public Facebook statuses for a particular keyword. For some reason, it is not doing what I expect it to do. A sample URL where the JSON would be found would be: http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Beatles

Right now, it is not printing any results. Can anyone spot the error in this?

```
<input type="text" id="query" /><button>add</button><br />
<div id="results">

</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var url='http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=';
var query;
    $('button').click(function(){
        query=$("#query").val();
        $.getJSON(url+query,function(json){
            $.each(json.data,function(i,feed){
                 if(feed.type=='status') {
                        $("#results").append('<p>'+feed.message+'</p>');                 
                 }
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What errors do you see in your debugger?  What do you see in the JS console when you use `console.info(feed.type);` and `console.info(feed.message);`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot retrieve data from an external URL ([same origin policy)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) . It is only possible with [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP), which the Facebook API supports. You have to add `callback=?` to your URL in order to use it:

```
var url='http://graph.facebook.com/search?callback=?&q=';
```

*(This is also done in the Twitter example you linked to in your comment to the now deleted answer)*